# What do "got a guard" and "torch" mean in the High School Musical 1 Movie?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I watched the film High School Musical 1 (2006) and there are some phrases that confuse me. Here is [the video on youtube](http://youtu.be/pmamm1U98Ak) and its transcript:

> [Mrs. Bolton enters the gym to find her son and husband busy shooting
>   hoops]
>
> Coach Bolton: (bounces ball to Troy) Keep working left, Troy. **Got a
>   guard** in the championship game we're expectin'. You'll **torch**
>   'em!

1. Does 'Got a guard' mean to protect the championship? Or does it means Troy has a job as a defender?
2. The word 'torch' in the dictionary means to burn something. I guess in this context, it means to defeat the other team. Am I right?

Comment: Torch here is meaning that the opposite team will be defeated very badly. Not so sure about the *Got a Guard*. Google indicates that **Guard Championship** is organised in some schools.

Comment: You have to see the scene in order to figure out what the coach is trying to say.

Comment: @SmokerAtStadium: I've already added the video link into my pose. Could you check it again?

Comment: I think your transcript is in error: What he says "Got a guard in that championship game **won't expect it**. You'll torch **him**." In this context *won't expect it* means ***who** won't expect it.* I think this confirms @J.R.'s answer.

Comment: @StoneyB. J.R. has provided some interpretation, but I don't know which one is suitable for the video. Could you help me choose one? Thanks

Comment: I think J.R. got it ... Note that the boy feints to what would be his right if he were facing his father, pulls him in that direction, then wheels around him to sink the basket without opposition.

Comment: @StoneyB: If what he says is "Got a guard in that championship game won't expect it", why doesn't he expect it? What does 'it' mean? Doesn't he expect his son to be the guard or doesn't he expect the championship game?

Comment: The father, who has scouted the opposing team, tells his son "Keep working left. Got (*=you've got=you are going to encounter*) a guard (*on the other team*) in that championship (*who*) won't expect it (*=your working left*). You'll torch (*=soundly defeat*) him." Exactly as J.R. says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not seen this movie, so I can't say for sure, but it's worth pointing out that *guard* is one of the positions on a basketball team, along with *center* and *forward*.

So, one possible meaning of this dialogue would be that the coach is talking about a particular player – a guard on the opposing team.

"Keep working left" might mean that the coach knows this player doesn't guard well on the left, or perhaps that he "cheats" to the right. (At the high school level, many players will overdefend on the right side, figuring the opposing player probably isn't all that skilled with their weak hand).

So, this is one possible interpretation:

- There is a player on the opposing team, who plays guard.
- I think this player might be guarding you during the game.
- I've seen this player play defense, he likes to overdefend on the right side.
- If you can drive to the hoop dribbling the ball with your left hand, you'll "torch" him (meaning, "you'll dribble right past him, and have a chance for an easy lay-up").

That's certainly all plausible, although, without having seen the movie, it's entirely possible that the dialog means something else. But, with the context I'm provided here, that's certainly a valid interpretation, and it explains both *guard* and *torch* in this context.

"Torch" is indeed slang for "burn"; however, in the context of athletics, I think it's more likely to be used when referring to one particular play than for an entire game.

> Fred was really burned on that play!
>   Yes, I hope he can defend better next time.

Comment: Extremly thank you. I have just uploaded the part of the movie on Youtube: http://youtu.be/pmamm1U98Ak. Could you watch the video and help me determine the meaning of 'got a guard' again?